# Targeting inline style with jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is the output HTML:

```
<ol id="aw-ln-filter-1-options" style="overflow: hidden; height: 250px;">
  <li style="padding-left:0px">
  </li>
  <li style="padding-left:10px">
  </li>
  <li style="padding-left:20px">
  </li>
  <li style="padding-left:10px">
  </li>
  <li style="padding-left:10px">
  </li>
</ol>
```

My jQuery:

```
jQuery(function ($) {

if ($('#aw-ln-filter-1-options li').css('padding-left') == '20px')
    {
       $(body).hide();
    }
});
```

I'm just using body hide as a test. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: your selector returns a collection of list elements, calling `.css('padding-left')` on it will only return the value of the first element in the collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't apply the `css()`-function to a collection of jQuery elements. You have to iterate them and test each one individually:

```
$('#aw-ln-filter-1-options li').each(
    function(i,e) {
      if ($(e).css('padding-left') == "20px") {
        $(e).css('background', 'red');
      }
    }
);
```

See example here: https://jsbin.com/hekokeqabu/edit?html,js,output

Maybe using jQuery's `filter()`-function together with the [attribute Contains Selector [name*=”value”]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) selector would also work, but I have found this really hard to get right in the past.

However, not knowing your use-case, I'd advice against using inline-styles as a marker for any select operation. One redesign will break everything. Use CSS-classes.

Comment: Perfect thanks. That makes sense that it wouldn't apply to a collection of elements. 

Unfortunately there's a plugin that is outputting the list items that I have no control over so targeting the inline styles seems to be the only way.